# How to set image and text in front of gradientLayer on UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, layer

My code looks like this:

```
    pickerCountry = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    pickerCountry.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - pickerCountry.frame.size.width, 50, 100, 100)
    pickerCountry.center.x = self.view.center.x
    pickerCountry.setTitle("Start1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    pickerCountry.setImage(UIImage(named: "Britain_mdpi.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    pickerCountry.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerCountry.titleLabel?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerCountry.layer.cornerRadius = 2

    pickerCountry.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 200)
    pickerCountry.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 50, bottom: 5, right: 5)

    pickerCountry.addTarget(self, action: "countryPicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    ContentView.addSubview(pickerCountry)
```

and I add gradient in a `func` like this:

```
    let colorTop = UIColor(netHex:0xffffff).CGColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(netHex:0xebebeb).CGColor

    pickerCountryGradientLayer.masksToBounds = true
    pickerCountryGradientLayer.cornerRadius = pickerCountry.layer.cornerRadius
    pickerCountryGradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    pickerCountryGradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]

    pickerCountry.layer.insertSublayer(pickerCountryGradientLayer, below: pickerCountry.imageView?.layer)
```

When I use this last line, `insertSublayer` like this I see the image, and I sort of see the title, but its color is white, or something, kind of weird. I set the color to black, so if this really does work, how do I change the title color?

I tried using `addSublayer`, but then I see title label and not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you've set your `UIButton`'s title color but I don't see where you're setting your `UIButton`'s title color. Use:

```
pickerCountry.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: my bad, i thought tintColor is title color, it worked till now, thank you